# How to use Docker Swarm Mode to share data between containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-cloud

I have just started using docker . I was able to create a docker compose file which deploys three components of my application ,with the necessary number of replications in one host .
I want to replicate the same same thing ,with multiple hosts now .
I have three processes A[7 copies ] ,B [ 1 copy] ,C [1 Copy]
I followed the creating swarm tutorial on the docker website ,and managed to create a manager and attach two workers to it .

So now when I run my command

```
 docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml perf
```

It does spawn the required number of machines ,but all of them in the manager itself . 
I would ideally want them to spawn C and B in the manager and ann the copies of A distributed between worker 1 and worker 2.
Here is my docker -compose file

```
version: '3'

services:

  A:
    image: A:host
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - LogFilesLocationFolder:/jmeter/log
      - AntOutLogFolder:/antout
      - ZipFilesLocationFolder:/zip
    deploy:
      replicas: 7
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]
    networks:
      - perfhost

  B:
    container_name: s1_perfSqlDB
    restart: always
    tty: true
    image: mysql:5.5
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:  
      - "3306:3306"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
       - perfhost

  C:
    container_name: s1_scheduler
    image: C:host
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - LogFilesLocationFolder:/log
      - ZipFilesLocationFolder:/zip
      - AntOutLogFolder:/antout
    networks:
      - perfhost
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"


networks:
  perfhost:

volumes:
     mysql:
     LogFilesLocationFolder:
     ZipFilesLocationFolder:
     AntOutLogFolder:
```

B) And if I do get this working ,how do I use volumes to transfer data between Conatiner for Service A  and container for Service B  ,given that they are on different host machines

Answer (score 2):

A few tips and answers:

- for service names I don't recommend capital letters. Use valid DNS hostnames (lowercase, no special char except -).
- container_name isn't supported in swarm and shouldn't be needed. Looks like C: should be something like `scheduler`, etc. Make the service names simple so they are easy to use/remember on their virtual network.
- All services in a single compose file are always on the same docker network in swarm (and docker-compose for local development), so no need for the network assignment or listing.
- restart:always isn't needed in swarm. That setting isn't used and is the default anyways. If you're using it for docker-compose, it's rarely needed as you usually don't want apps in a respawn loop during errors which will usually result in CPU race condition. I recommend leaving it off.
- Volumes use a "volume driver". The default is `local`, just like normal docker commands. If you have shared storage you can use a volume driver plugin from store.docker.com to ensure shared storage is connected to the correct node.
- If you're still having issues with worker/manager task assignment, put the output of `docker node ls` and maybe `docker service ls` and `docker node ps <managername>` for us to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks alot @Bret ,this clears up a lot of things, I did get the swarm working ,there was a problem witht he container images its working now. I read one of your other answers where you recommend Rex-ray ,ill try using that for the persistence . Just wondering though ,does rex Ray allow for multiple clients to read and write on a common storage volume ? or Can I achieve that through the volume driver plugin ?

Comment: Basically I need to transfer data from service C to the 7 copies of service A  ,Even if I use individual volumes ,so at any point of time two services A and C would be connected to the volume.   I don't think RexRay allows this  ,is there some other plugin I can use for this ? Flocker maybe ?

Comment: In the case of most volume drivers, they just enable you to use whatever underlying *shared storage* you want. The features of *that* storage will dictate if you can have multiple read/write connections to that storage volume. For example: AWS EBS and DigitalOcean Block Storage would only let one container connect at a time (one-to-one relationship). AWS EFS would allow many-to-one due to it's design as NFS network storage. REX-Ray just automates the connection process.

Comment: Flocker is dead. If you need full file replication, consider portworx.com but it still won't do open files (like databases) correctly I think. For that you want app-level replication (database clusters, etc.)

Comment: My primary requirment is to have multiple applicatios share some files before trying to dockerize the whole set-up I was using a simple shared folder in Windows for the purposes. From what I understand I think a NFS partition should do the work for me ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should run
`docker node ls`
And check if all of your nodes are available. If they are, you should check if the workers have the images they need to run the containers.
I would also try with a constraint using the id of each node instead, you can see the ids with the previous command.

Comment: hi ,yes I did run the command as instructed in the documentation to validate ,the workers are connected to manager . To connect I had used the command with comes as output when I fire up the manager .

Comment: @Imrak I waswondering if the docker-compose document is proper or not, because in the documet I havenent mentioned anywhere to distribute the service A between 2 workers ,what if there are multiple workers present ,does docker take care of that on its own ?

Comment: Yes, a single docker service with multiple replicas will scale out by default.

Comment: As @BretFisher mentioned, docker will scale by default. Note - the exception is, when you are running a service in global mode, where each node will run a single instance. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_scale/#extended-description

Answer (score 0):

Run before `docker stack deploy`:

```sh
mkdir /srv/service/public
docker run --rm -v /srv/service/public:/srv/service/public my-container-with-data cp -R /var/www/app/public /srv/service/public
```

Use direcory `/srv/service/public` as volume in containers.